# [JAVA Help using 'for' and reusing methods from other parts of the class

Tags: java, for-loop

I need some help with 2 methods that I'm using. 
My first method looks at each character after the first (0th) in the string s and checks if they're digits but I cannot get it to fully work.

```
/**
* Forms the latter 5 characters of the accountNum String into a substring 
which is checked to
* see if all characters are positive integers
*/
public Boolean hasValidDigits(String s)
{
 for(int i=1; i<s.length(); i++)
    if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))  {
    return true;
   }
}
```

The issue with the method is it's asking for a return statement for the 'for' and I'm not sure why.

My second method calls methods from other parts of the class to check a string s.

```
/**
* Checks the following three criteria:
* - Is a string of length 6
* - Starts with a capital Letter
* - Subsequent characters are positive integers
*/
public Boolean isValidAccountNum(String s)
{
  if (s.isValidLength() s.isValidStart() s.hasValidDigits())  {
  return true;
  } else {
     return false;
 }
}
```

The issue with this method is it's saying "Cannot find symbol - method isValidLength()

I'm guessing it would have same error with the other methods.

The methods I want to call are all made public. I'll include the isValidLength() below.

```
/**
* Checks if the variable accountNum has a length of 6 characters
*/
public Boolean isValidLength(String s)
{
if (s.length()==6) {
  return true;
   } else {
    return false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first method might not return anything if your if condition is not true so you need to return something at last line of function.
Your second method does not have passed any parameters and syntactically incorrect as well.

Please check out your language syntax first and practice some basic examples for your understanding of java

Answer (score 0):

The first method might performs a loop but will return at the first iteration if it is a digit it does not check the whole string and there is no `false` returned e.g.:

```
public Boolean hasValidDigits(String s) {
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

the `isValidAccountNum` method can just return the statement as it is already a boolean expression

```
return s.isValidLength() && s.isValidStart() && s.hasValidDigits();
```

same for the `isValidLength` method for the same reason:

```
return s.length()==6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your methods accept a `String` as a parameter, they are not part of the `String` class. So you have to do this `isValidLength(s)` rather than `s.isValidLength()`.

Further, you cant have multiple method calls inside the parenthesis of an `if` statement, without a logical operator in between (`&&` for `and`, `||` for `or`).

Also, your `hasValidDigits` does not do what you think, it will return true if one of the character is a digit, rather than all of them. Also, the first part of the javadoc comment on this method is nowhere near true. It also lacks a return when the if statement never evaluates to `true`.

So what you want is something like this:

```
public Boolean isValidLength(String s) {
    return s.length == 6;
}

//this checks all characters of the string though, 
//your javadoc said something about checking the last 5 characters..
public Boolean hasValidDigits(String s) {
    for(int i=1; i<s.length(); i++)
        if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))  {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public Boolean isValidAccountNum(String s) {
  return isValidLength(s) && isValidStart(s) && hasValidDigits(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, slowly starting to understand java better <3